# Set window as default focus target in Xorg (no window manager)

Tags: xorg

I'm trying to run a full screen program directly under Xorg (with no window manager or anything else because it's not necessary and I don't want to use any more resources than necessary) such that it can open another full screen program on top of itself but when that other full screen program closes it will receive focus again. (This need to open a second full screen program on top of itself is why I'm not using the frame buffer, which is what I was originally using).

I have the first half of this working, in that I can start an X server with just the first full screen program in my xinitrc, and it takes over the display and looks fine and can open the second full screen program, and the second full screen program will go full screen on top of it and work fine, including receiving input, but when I close the second full screen program, the first one doesn't receive any key presses or other events anymore. Is there a way to fix this?